# Why aren't placeholders for arguments more common?

Tags: derivatives, notation

When learning about differentiation and integration, one often deals with functions, and it's common to use $D(x^2) = 2x$ as a function instead of $D(x\mapsto x^2) = (x\mapsto 2x)$, while it would make more sense to use placeholders such as $D(\cdot^2)(x) = (2\cdot)(x) = (2x)$ to mark the difference. While it's useful to use $x$ as a placeholder, this is often confusing when learning about functions with functions as their argument. So why isn't it more common to use such a placeholder when describing functions?

Comment: Why is $D_x (x^2)$ confusing?

Comment: @GFauxPas What is $D_x\left(3^2\right)$?

Comment: @GitGud $D_x(3^2) = 0$. $\left.{D_x(x^2)}\right\vert_{x = 3} = 6$.

Comment: @GFauxPas No, it doesn't work that way. You can't look at things as constants and as functions at your convenience while still being consistent. You're either lazy and inconsistent or consistent and write out things appropriately.

Comment: @GFauxPas $D_x(x^2)$ is confusing because it's abuse of notation. The $D_x$-function only works on functions, not some expression $x^2$. Using the same symbols for both the expression $x^2$ and $x\mapsto x^2$ _is_ confusing.